# schedule: click book time slot to display image of specific user that is booking? HOW PLEASE?

Tags: php, sql, image

Ok, i have my php code wrote out for the schedule to book time slots. The sql is pulling the user name (text) and displaying it, BUT I AM NOW TRYING TO DISPLAY THE USERS PIC IMAGE INSTEAD OF JUST NAME(text).  I cant for the life of me find anything that is clearly telling me how to display an image on click instead of the text from sql. PLEASE HELP, THANKS :)

ENTIRE CODE:

```
<?php require('head.php');?>

<?php
// Basic info
$slotb = $_GET['slot'];
$day = $_GET['day'];

// User info
$username = $_SESSION['rp_username'];
$avatar = $_SESSION['rp_avatar'];
$rank = $_SESSION['rp_rank'];

// Get user's ID
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM rp_users WHERE username = '$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

$userid = $row['id'];
}

// Determine day of week
if($_GET['week'] == "")
{

$_GET['week'] = date("l");
}


// Determine day of week
if($_GET['day'] == ""){
$day = $_GET['week'];

$_GET['week'] = date("l"); 
}


// Get slot info
$slot = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day =        '$day'"));



// Timetable heading
echo "<div id='timetable'><center><b><u>Timetable</u></b><p>
<h1>-You are currently viewing $day's timetable-</h1><p>
<a href='?week=Monday'>Monday</a> | <a href='?week=Tuesday'>Tuesday</a> | <a href='?      week=Wednesday'>Wednesday</a> | <a href='?week=Thursday'>Thursday</a> | <a href='? week=Friday'>Friday</a> | <a href='?week=Saturday'>Saturday</a> | <a href='? week=Sunday'>Sunday</a><br><hr><br>";



// Process booking
if($_GET["action"] == "book")
{

if($slot[$slotb] == "")
{

$command = mysql_query("UPDATE rp_timetable SET `$slotb` = '$userid' WHERE day =     '$day'") or die(mysql_error());

if($command)
{

echo "<center><h1>Successfully booked slot!</h1></center><br/>";

$slot = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day =  '$day'"));

}else{

echo "<center><h1>ERROR - An unknown error occurred, please try again.</h1></center>    <br/>";

}

}else{

echo "<center><h1>The selected slot is already booked!</h1></center><br/>";

}

}elseif($_GET["action"] == "unbook")
{

if($slot[$slotb] == $userid || $rank == "Administrator")

{

$command = mysql_query("UPDATE rp_timetable SET `$slotb` = '' WHERE day = '$day'") or   die(mysql_error());

if($command)
{

echo "<center><h1>Successfully unbooked slot!</h1></center><br/>";

$slot = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day =    '$day'"));

}else{

echo "<center><h1>ERROR - An unknown error occurred, please try again.</h1></center> <br/>";

}

}else{

echo "<center><h1>You cannot unbook this slot!</h1></center><br/>";

}
}
elseif($_GET["action"] == "empty"){

if($rank == "Administrator")
{

$command = mysql_query("UPDATE rp_timetable SET `1`='', `2`='', `3`='', `4`='', `5`='',   `6`='', `7`='', `8`='', `9`='', `10`='', `11`='', `12`='', `13`='', `14`='', `15`='',   `16`='', `17`='', `18`='', `19`='', `20`='', `21`='', `22`='', `23`='', `24`='' WHERE  day='$day'") or die(mysql_error());
    if($command)
{

echo "<center><h1>Successfully cleared all slots for day!</h1></center><br/>";


$slot = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_timetable WHERE day =  '$day'"));


}else{

echo "<center><h1>ERROR - An unknown error occurred, please try again.</h1></center><br/>";

}

}
else{

echo "<center><h1>Only administrators may unbook all slots for the day!</h1></center>    <br/>";
}

}


// Start of timetable
echo "<table border='0' valign='middle' align='center'><tr>
<td width='150px' align='center'><b><u>Time</u></b></td>
<td width='150px' align='center'><b><u>DJ Booked</u></b><td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>";



// Display each timeslot/table
function outit($time, $num)
{

global $day, $slot, $userid, $rank;


$info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rp_users WHERE id =   '".$slot[$num]."'"));

if($slot[$num] == "")
{ 

$book[$num] = "<a href='?action=book&day=$day&slot=$num'>BOOK SLOT</a>"; 

}
elseif($userid == $slot[$num] || $rank == "Administrator")
{

$book[$num] = "<a href='?action=unbook&day=$day&slot=$num'><b>DJ ".$info['avatar']."   (Unbook)</a></b>";

}else{

$book[$num] = "<b><font color='black'>DJ ".$info['avatar']."</font></b>";

}

if($num%2)
{

echo "<tr class='colour'><td width='150px' align='center'>$time</td><td width='150px'    align='center'>".$book[$num]."<td></tr>";

}else{

echo "<tr><td width='150px' align='center'>$time</td><td width='150px'   align='center'>".$book[$num]."<td></tr>";

}
}


// Print it out
outit('12:00 - 01:00 AM', 1);
$i = 2;
while($i <= 12)
{

$start_time = $i - 1;
$end_time = $i;
if(strlen($start_time) == 1){$start_time = "0".$start_time;}

if(strlen($end_time) == 1){$end_time = "0".$end_time;}

$full_time = "$start_time:00 - $end_time:00 AM";

outit($full_time, $i);

$i++;
}
outit('12:00 - 01:00 PM', 13);
$i = 14;
while($i <= 24)
{

$start_time = $i - 13;
$end_time = $i - 12;
if(strlen($start_time) == 1){$start_time = "0".$start_time;}

if(strlen($end_time) == 1){$end_time = "0".$end_time;}

$full_time = "$start_time:00 - $end_time:00 PM";

outit($full_time, $i);

$i++;
}


// Bottom of timetable
echo "<tr><td align='center'>---------------</td><td align='center'>---------------  </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td width='150px' align='center'><b>$day</b></td>
<td width='150px' align='center'>";

if ($_SESSION["rp_rank"] == "Administrator")
{ 

echo("<a href='?action=empty&day=$day'>CLEAR DAY</a>");
}


echo "</td></tr></table>
</center><p></div>";
?>


<?php require('bottom.php');?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the php you're using to echo the query results? And also a few example rows of the output you're getting?

Comment: You modify the query to also select the image url to display. Then display it.

Comment: @Darren which query in that code is selecting the URL of the user's image? Also on what table and on what field is that image url?

Comment: alright, there is the code fella's, plz any help is appreciate it:)                    i did try that line of code Brian and got output error of: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 92

Comment: @DB the code was just an example, it assumes you had a query that selected a field called image_url and had given the array a variable of $row , you have to modify it to suit your situation. If you want us to do that for you, we need to know on what table and on what field that image URL exists. I do not see any queries in your code that seem to indicate an image url being selected

Comment: @Brain  Thanks ahead of time for your patients man.  Under the user info section, we have changed $djname to $avatar, this is where we are getting stuck, we are needing the correct input code/place of input to display the avatar from the sql. Our query is coming from the username = $userid.

Answer (score 0):

To use the $avatar variable that seems to be stored in your session:

```
echo '<img src="'.$avatar.'"></img';
```

You also seem to be selecting that field in the query $info, meaning you should be able to use the following as well:

```
echo '<img src="'.$info['avatar'].'"></img';
```

To isolate the problem, please let me know what output you get for just the following:

```
<?php require('head.php');?>

<?php
// Basic info
$slotb = $_GET['slot'];
$day = $_GET['day'];

// User info
$username = $_SESSION['rp_username'];
$avatar = $_SESSION['rp_avatar'];
$rank = $_SESSION['rp_rank'];


echo $avatar;


<?php require('bottom.php');?>
```

My guess is that $avatar holds apostrophes or other characters that need to be escaped.

Also could you provide a couple examples of the field values for the avatar column on the rp_users table? If they contain apostrophes, then that is your answer.

Comment: Try and add something to the question about how OP would modify the query to select the image url as it seems he hasnt even tried that so your answer wont help him at all.

Comment: @Darren it seems he is selecting the name of the image but that it's just displaying as text. Of course, that is my assumption based on very limited information. But when he says "user's pic image instead of just name(text)" that very much seems to me like he's grabbing the URL, just that it's displaying as text, and that his problem is turning the text into an image.

Comment: Actually you have a good point there Brian, I assumed he was grabbing the user's name "text" instead of the actual image url as text!

Comment: @Brain Thanks ahead of time for your patients man. Under the user info section, we have changed $djname to $avatar, this is where we are getting stuck, we are needing the correct input code/place of input to display the avatar from the sql. Our query is coming from the username = $userid.

Comment: @DB it looks like $userid is the variable you've given to the result of the query called $sql, column "id". In reviewing all of the columns being selected in all of your queries I don't see anything that would indicate an avatar or user image. Is there a column on the "rp_users" table that holds the image URL? If so, you'll want to select it. After it's selected you can use my code above to echo it back, but you would change "image_url" to the name of the column

Comment: yes, the column is "avatar" and when using your code above as in    echo '<img src="'.$row['avatar'].'"></img>';               thats how i have  it inserted and getting the: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: @DB can you update your code to whatever you're running now? There are no queries that select a field called avatar in your code.

Comment: @Brian ok i just updated to exactly what it looks like as we are currently working on it. With it like that, its displaying the sql link in text form.

Comment: @DB the avatar is stored in your session (at least it should be as that's where you're saying it's coming from, in your code). You aren't returning the avatar in your query, as I had thought. In that case you should be able to use the code in my edit. This does assume you're actually storing the avatar in the session

Comment: Changed error code when inserted:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO...   where are you placing echo code exactly?

Comment: Are you placing it inside of quotation marks somewhere? You should be able to use it anywhere after you define the $avatar variable, as a test just try putting it on its own on line 47, you can download a txt file where I've inserted it here http://shwivel.synology.me:5000/fbsharing/6bR8HesQ , if it's still not working I'll check back tomorrow

Comment: that just broke down the entire table, with no images on any click or input.

Comment: @DB to diagnose the problem please test the code I just put into the edit which echoes only the avatar variable. It should display as text, please paste what text that is and provide some example values in the avatar column. My guess is that column has values with apostrophes that need to be escaped.